# Proof for X and Y independent if joint c.d.f. of both variables is the product of c.d.f of each of the two variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, independence

The book I am reading says the following:

For any two variables $X$ and $Y$, if for every two sets $A$ and $B$ of real numbers $Pr(X \in A \cap Y \in B) =Pr(X \in A )Pr( Y \in B)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Further, if we can show that $P(X \leq x \cap Y \leq y) = P(X \leq x)P(Y \leq y)$, then we can conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Does anybody have a proof for this last statement? My book has omitted the proof.

Comment: Have you seen a proof that the distribution function determines the distribution?  That would make very short work of this problem.

Comment: @whuber I am afraid not. Could you share a link or something?

Comment: A modern textbook on probability or probability and measure would include a rigorous account.  Just about any textbook on probability and statistics will at least assert this result and perhaps demonstrate it in simple cases.